# JSON Parsing to retrieve and display the values of attributes in a textbox (WIndows Phone 8)

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I am trying to parse a JSON from a URL and retrieve it's data value of each attribute and display it in a textbox. But i am facing this error: 
"An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code" Error reading integer. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path 'BusRoute[0].STEPS

This are my codes:

```
         // Create webclient.
         WebClient client = new WebClient();

         client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
         client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.onemap.sg/publictransportation/service1.svc/routesolns?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&sl=39167.4524,35518.8625&el=28987.5163,33530.5653&startstop=&endstop=&walkdist=300&mode=bus&routeopt=cheapest&retgeo=true&maxsolns=1&callback="));
    }

            /*public void loadHTMLCallback(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
            string content = e.Result;
            tb_json.Text = content ;
            }*/


            public class BusRoute
            {
            public int SOLUTION { get; set; }
            public string DURATION { get; set; }
            public string TOTALCARD { get; set; }
            public string TOTALCASH { get; set; }
            public string TOTALDISTANCE { get; set; }
            public int STEPS { get; set; }
            public string TYPE { get; set; }
            public string SERVICETYPE { get; set; }
            public string SERVICEID { get; set; }
            public string NUMBEROFSTOP { get; set; }
            public string BOARDID { get; set; }
            public string BOARDDESC { get; set; }
            public string BOARDDIST { get; set; }
            public string ALIGHTID { get; set; }
            public string ALIGHTDESC { get; set; }
            public string ALIGHTDIST { get; set; }
            public int TOTALSTOPS { get; set; }
            public string PATH { get; set; }

            }

            public class RootObject
            {
            public List<BusRoute> BusRoute { get; set; }
            }

            void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
                foreach (var route in rootObject.BusRoute)
            {
             int t = route.TOTALSTOPS;
             string totalStops = t.ToString();
             tb_test.Text = "Total number of stops: " + totalStops;
            }
         }
```

Please give me some guidance on how I can retrieve the attributes and display it in the textbox. Thank you!

Comment: Can you print rootObject after deserialization?

Comment: No, I can't. @Lee Gary

Comment: Can you debug it? I.e. create desktop project and step through?

Comment: can you do a quick watch or something and see what's being deserialized?

Comment: The error you got was because the JSON returning collection/array as value of `STEPS` property when you have it as single-valued property type (integer) in model class. Fix your model as suggested by @LeeGary (using json2csharp to generate model class is handy to avoid this kind of mistake).

Comment: Thank you for all the help! @Lee Gary Thanks for the codes, it works and it helps me a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving "images" from a JSON string retrived from Instagram API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729997/retrieving-images-from-a-json-string-retrived-from-instagram-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tried using your json url: http://www.onemap.sg/publictransportation/service1.svc/routesolns?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&sl=39167.4524,35518.8625&el=28987.5163,33530.5653&startstop=&endstop=&walkdist=300&mode=bus&routeopt=cheapest&retgeo=true&maxsolns=1&callback=

(is the token safe to be put here on public internet?)

Generated class from http://json2csharp.com

```
public class STEP
{
    public string STEP { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string ServiceType { get; set; }
    public string ServiceID { get; set; }
    public string NumberOfStop { get; set; }
    public string BoardId { get; set; }
    public string BoardDesc { get; set; }
    public string BoardDist { get; set; }
    public string AlightId { get; set; }
    public string AlightDesc { get; set; }
    public string AlightDist { get; set; }
}

public class BusRoute
{
    public string Solution { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public string TotalCard { get; set; }
    public string TotalCash { get; set; }
    public string TotalDistance { get; set; }
    public List<STEP> STEPS { get; set; }
    public string TotalStops { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> PATH { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<BusRoute> BusRoute { get; set; }
}



var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result); <- this works
```